# Need help passing Windows Event HANDLE by reference to a class

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

The program idea is to run a loop in thread procedure Setxxx() and at the end of the loop, wait on an event. Once the event fires, the loop resumes.

This Setxxx() function is in a class and its caller creates the event, the thread and passes the event to the class constructor.

I thought if I passed in a pointer to the HANDLE, I could call ResetEvent to unblock the thread. But the problem is the WaitForSingleObjectEx function returns w/out waiting. Its return code is 6 (DWORD) invalid handle.

How can I pass in the handle such that I can control the thread by unblocking with ResetEvent?

```
// header file
class CPropertyMarker {
public:
    CPropertyMarker(HANDLE **hThreadSignalEvent);
    void Setxxx();
private:
    bool m_Run;
    HANDLE* m_hThreadSignalEvent;
};

// class file
CPropertyMarker::CPropertyMarker(HANDLE **hThreadSignalEvent) {
    m_hThreadSignalEvent = *hThreadSignalEvent;
}
void CPropertyMarker::Setxxx() {
    DWORD retVal = 0;
    while(m_Run) {
        try {
            // statements snipped
        }
        catch(exception){}
        ResetEvent(m_hThreadSignalEvent);
        WaitForSingleObjectEx(&m_hThreadSignalEvent, INFINITE, false);
    }
}

// caller 
m_hEventMainThread  = (HANDLE*)CreateEvent(NULL, true, true, L"xxx-adsfsdfblah_yyy");
m_PropMarker        = new CPropertyMarker(&m_hEventMainThread);
m_PropMarker->SetRunState(true);
m_hThreadMain       = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &CFromMyClass::Setxxx, (LPVOID)m_PropMarker, 0, &m_ThreadMainId);
```

Comment: You are trying too hard. You can simply pass `HANDLE`s by value. Under the hood, a `HANDLE` is declared as a `void*`, so really just a POD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m_hThreadSignalEvent` is a `HANDLE*` so you need to dereference it. You would need to change your code to:

```
   ResetEvent(*m_hThreadSignalEvent);
   WaitForSingleObjectEx(*m_hThreadSignalEvent, INFINITE, false);
```

However your `CPropertyMarker` constructor is also odd, as it takes a `HANDLE**`, and dereferences it to get a `HANDLE*` which is almost certainly not correct. You seem to have too many levels of indirection. A `HANDLE` is a pointer in its own right, you very rarely would need to use `HANDLE*` anywhere.

I would look at changing your code to:

```
// header file
class CPropertyMarker {
public:
    CPropertyMarker(HANDLE hThreadSignalEvent);
    void Setxxx();
private:
    bool m_Run;
    HANDLE m_hThreadSignalEvent;
};

// class file
CPropertyMarker::CPropertyMarker(HANDLE hThreadSignalEvent) {
    m_hThreadSignalEvent = hThreadSignalEvent;
}
void CPropertyMarker::Setxxx() {
    DWORD retVal = 0;
    while(m_Run) {
        try {
            // statements snipped
        }
        catch(exception){}
        ResetEvent(m_hThreadSignalEvent);
        WaitForSingleObjectEx(m_hThreadSignalEvent, INFINITE, false);
    }
}

// caller 
m_hEventMainThread  = CreateEvent(NULL, true, true, L"xxx-adsfsdfblah_yyy");
m_PropMarker        = new CPropertyMarker(m_hEventMainThread);
```

Comment: Ahh, I was about to type up that one level of indirection should be removed. Don't forget to change `m_hEventMainThread  = (HANDLE)CreateEvent(..)`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!! The pointer to a pointer to a pointer was ruminants of rat-holing and I just left that in since it didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Actually,

```
WaitForSingleObjectEx(&m_hThreadSignalEvent, INFINITE, false);
```

should be

```
WaitForSingleObjectEx(*m_hThreadSignalEvent, INFINITE, false);
```

I would also add that your sample does not need to be using `HANDLE` pointers `(HANDLE *)` at all.